# C# ошибки при работе с xlsx файлами

Tags: c#, excel

Имеется код

```
private void buttonAct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            _wkb = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_wkb.Worksheets[1];                
            Excel.Range excelRange = worksheet.UsedRange;               
            object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(
                        Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
            //access the cells
            for (int row = 1; row <= worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; ++row)
            {                    
                articul = valueArray[row, 1].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            //clean up stuffs
            _wkb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_wkb);

            _excelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_excelApp);
        }

    }
```

При открытии книги Excel такая ошибка тровится

> Невозможно привести COM-объект типа "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass" к интерфейсному типу "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application". Операция завершилась со сбоем, поскольку вызов QueryInterface COM-компонента для интерфейса с IID "{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" возвратил следующую ошибку: Ошибка при загрузке библиотеки. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

Прошу помощи. Спасибо

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/968263/error-unable-to-cast-com-object--when-exporting-to-microsoft-excel-f

Comment: Переустановите офис. В коде все нормально.